# I want to fetch the ISO Date which is stored as "string" format in Mongodb and convert it to Date format in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to fetch the ISO Date which is stored as "string" format in Mongodb and convert it to Date format in Nodejs. Inside API I want to try

```
app.get('/hrTable', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/CSS_RAG", { 
        useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            var dbo = db.db("CSS_RAG");
            var query = {};
            for (var key in req.query) {  
                                            
                  req.query[key] !== "" ? query[key] = req.query[key] : null;
            }

            dbo.collection("hrTable").find(
              query,
  { sort: { Date: -1 } }).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) reject(err);

    db.close();
    resolve(result);
    res.send(result);
  }
  )})})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
date = new Date(ISODate("1960-07-30T00:00:00.000+0000"));
date.getFullYear()+'-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-'+date.getDate();
```

Comment: Hi Syed thanks for the workaround, since I am new to mean stack, I don't have clarity where to add this, I have written an API inside that I am connecting the mongodb and fetching the table infos,

Comment: You are fetching data from database once you get the data get date from it by what ever you named it in schema like db.createdAt and then in next line apply uppercode comming date from db will be in paramter